# Setup mock without changing `called` count

Tags: pytest, python-unittest.mock

let's say I want to test this function

```py
def my_function():
    my_obj = MyClass()
    return my_obj.my_method()
```

I want to mock `MyClass`, so I use `unittest.mock.patch`

```py
@patch('...MyClass')
def test_my_function(MyClass):
    MyClass().my_method.return_value = 'foo'
    assert my_function() == 'foo'
    MyClass.assert_called_once()
```

this test fails at the last line with the error `AssertionError: Expected 'MyClass' to have been called once. Called 2 times.`; witch, in a sense, is right: the first time is `test_my_function`, when I set up the `MyClass().my_method` return value.

What I want to express, however, is the fact that `MyClass()` should be instantiated just once in `my_function`.

Is there a way to "prepare" the nested mocks (so to set the `return_value = 'foo'`) without changing the intermediate mocks "called" count?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dumb me... It was enough to use `MyClass.return_value.my_method.return_value = 'foo'` instead of `MyClass().my_method.return_value = 'foo'`